# Launchd item no longer firing in Snow Leopard

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, launchd

A launchd item that was working in 10.5 is no longer working after my upgrade to 10.6. I am running 10.6.2 and I have recreated the launchd item and given it a new name and that one doesn't run either.

I have found a link of people with the same problem on [google groups](http://groups.google.com/group/macenterprise/browse_thread/thread/bc9e450adde296c2/08d9e6cff7528768?lnk=raot&pli=1) but none of the advice in that link helps. My launchd item is not listed in `/private/var/db/launchd.db/com.apple.launchd/overrides.plist` or in any of the overrides.plist files in the subdirectories of `/private/var/db/launchd.db/`

I have also tried to set this up as both a user agent and a user daemon.

My launchd item simply runs a shell script, which I have no problem launching manually.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.eric.tmnotify.launchd</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/<path_to>/tmnotify.sh</string>
    </array>
    <key>StartInterval</key>
    <integer>3600</integer>
</dict>
</plist>
```

I have tried to load it by overriding the disabled key (even though it is not disabled in any of the overrides.plist files) with both:

```
sudo launchctl load -F /Users/eric/Library/LaunchAgents/com.eric.tmnotify.launchd.plist
sudo launchctl load -w /Users/eric/Library/LaunchAgents/com.eric.tmnotify.launchd.plist
```

and after running either of them I can see that it is running by using `sudo launchctl list` but the shell script never fires.

Edit: I have also put this in the formerly blank file at `/private/var/db/launchd.db/com.apple.launchd.peruser.501/overrides.plist` :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
        <key>com.eric.tmnotify.launchd</key>
        <dict>
                <key>Disabled</key>
                <false/>
        </dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```

I also tried inserting this alphabetically:

```
    <key>com.eric.tmnotify.launchd</key>
    <dict>
            <key>Disabled</key>
            <false/>
    </dict>
```

into the file `/private/var/db/launchd.db/com.apple.launchd/overrides.plist` but still no dice.

Comment: Have you checked system.log for any relevant messages?
tmnotify.sh is executable?
And a stupid question - but the user account 'eric' - it is logged in?

Comment: The account is logged in and the script is executable. There is nothing in the logs.

Comment: Have you looked at http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/technotes/tn2005/tn2083.html and the key `LimitLoadToSessionType`. I don't know if it'll cure your problem, but might be worth checking out.

Comment: I'll read through that some more, but it doesn't look like that applies to this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The release of Lingon for Snow Leopard in the Mac App Store solves this one.

Comment: One has to wonder what you are paying $4.99 for. Lingon 2.1.1 is free, open source, and works (find it on http://SF.net). MAS is selling 2.2. Somehow I doubt there have been any changes since 2.1.1. Perhaps you can request 2.2 source and compile it yourself, if there were any changes.

Comment: 2.1.1 only supports up to 10.5. But the 2.2 release supports 10.6

Comment: Do you know what Lingon did that was different and got the plist to work?